# Node MySQL: How to insert multiple rows of data at once?

Tags: mysql, arrays, object

Pushing objects into an array is working correctly here, but I keep getting MySQL query errors related to syntax.  Not sure if the array of objects should be an array of arrays, or whether something in the query needs to be fixed.

```
  var array = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    array.push(
      {
        type: data[i].category,
        name: data[i].name
      }
    );
  };

  var query = 'INSERT INTO table (type, name) VALUES ?';
  connection.query(query, array, 
    function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    connection.end();
  });
```

Comment: Can you post screenshot of query errors and advise as to what each corresponding field in the database is setup as (text VS blob VS integer, etc)?

Comment: type is a reserved keyword, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html, so either use a non-keyword, or quote it properly, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html ...

Comment: The 'type' you want to replace isn't in the javascript loop, but in your mysql statement defined as the query variable.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I needed to create an array of arrays and insert that, without the object and keys.  For example,

```
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    array.push(
      [
        data[i].category,
        data[i].name
      ]
    );
  };
```

and

```
  connection.query(query, [arrayOfAlcohols], 
    function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
      connection.end();
  });
```