# NodeJS inserting multiple rows of data breaking on SQL statement

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql

I've seen from other asked questions on how to insert multiple rows of data into a single query ([Node MySQL: How to insert multiple rows of data at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47118240/node-mysql-how-to-insert-multiple-rows-of-data-at-once) and https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_insert.asp) but for some reason my sql syntax is not working, producing

```
error: syntax error at or near "?"
```

here is the code in question:

```
var arr = [];
teams.map((element) => {
    arr.push([element.fields.draws_total,
        element.fields.score_diff_formatted_total,
        element.fields.losses_total,
        element.fields.matches_total,
        element.team.name,
        element.fields.points_total,
        element.position,
        element.fields.wins_total]);
});
pool.connect();
var sql = 'INSERT INTO prem_standings (draws,goal_diff,losses,matches,name,points,position,wins) VALUES %L';
pool.query(sql, [arr], function(err, result) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    console.log(result);
    pool.end();
});
```

Figured out the issue. I am using PostgreSQL instead of MySQL, so instead of `?` it should be `%L`. updating code uploaded.

Comment: what values inside the arr?

Comment: @PaulMahardika updated my post to include what is in arr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using PostgreSQL instead of MySQL, so instead of ? it should be %L. Please close your question if got the answer